# Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project Settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, setup-project

I have a solution that contains three projects; UI (winforms), Business Layer and Data Access Layer, and I have created a setup project. I have added  UI project as a primary output, and other two projects (actually dlls) automatically added to application folder and these two projects appears under the Detected Dependencies folder in the solution.

After building the solution, I have installed the program. When I run the program, I get the following error:

`"Could not load file or assembly 'xxxBL', Version = 1.0.0.0 Culture = neutral, PublicKey Token = null or one of its dependencies."`
 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: xxxBL.dll is located c:\ProgramFiles\'MyCompany'\'MyProgram' folder

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the dll that failed to load is actually in the search path of your Application.  If it is, run the  [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the dll that failed to load to see why it failed to load.  Like the error message says it is possible that one of the dll's dependencies failed to load.  For instance, a common mistake occurs if you deploy a debug version of your dll.  It would work on your development machine since it most likely would have whaterver SDK you used already installed, but on a fresh machine it would fail to load because the debug dlls are not installed.  The Dependency Walker will allow you to find this sort of problem.